# Transparency fog performance

Tags: alpha-blending

Old games use Distance Fog to limit the draw distance and decrease the number of polygons drawn.

This is usually done by lerping the color to the fog color.
But what if this color is full transparency and the resulting color is alphablended with the underlying image?
Is Alpha blending in this case more performance heavy?

I am talking about an effect like this:
[image]

Answer (score -1):

I think its still distance fog just not so dense. Personally I'd either sample custom distance function or just go with one standard but lower its density.